# Can I fix my contractor's bad stain job?

Tags: wood, staining

The contractors I hired to restore my house put an extremely thick coat of stain on my floors and did not wipe off the excess. They left it sitting there for days and now there are puddles of dark, uneven, tacky stain all over.
This is the first coat and they are planning to do another. I told them to stop before they did anything else.
The stain is Minwax Red Oak. I'm not sure of the type of wood.

This seems wrong to me and from the sloppy work they have done on the rest of the house, I feel like I'm probably right. I am in Philadelphia and it's pretty cold right now. The temperature was their explanation for why this did it this way.

Can you confirm that this is bad and can it be fixed without standing and starting over?

[image: Bad stain]

Comment: Don't pay them until the floor is done to your satisfaction.   I have never seen stain done like that, but I am in Fla. where temp. is not an issue.

Comment: Their methodology doesn't match my recollection of Minwax's instructions, but Minwax makes many Red Oak products. You should specify which exact product they used. Or look up the technical data sheet yourself. Minwax also has a customer service line to call. If your contractor has diverged from their instructions, hopefully customer service will still have something to say (beyond "not it!").

Answer (score 1):

At this point I wouldn't intervene. I would be afraid of giving them an argument that my intervention caused any issues instead of their negligence. I would also be afraid of causing issues.

Comment: Thanks @papham This is essentially my plan - I'm fighting the urge to go in and try to fix everything myself.